# MongoDB : Count of distinct elements of array

Tags: mongodb, select, mongodb-query, distinct

I have following documents in MongoDB's collection :

```json
{
    "userid" : 1,
    "open" : [
        {
            "messageid" : 1441,
            "viewed" : ISODate("2015-03-24T00:50:00Z"),
        },
        {
            "messageid" : 1441,
            "viewed" : ISODate("2015-06-21T00:10:00Z"),
        },
        {
            "messageid" : 1527,
            "viewed" : ISODate("2015-06-21T07:52:00Z"),
        }
    ]
}
{
    "userid" : 2,
    "open" : [
        {
            "messageid" : 2155,
            "viewed" : ISODate("2015-09-15T15:32:00Z"),
        },
        {
            "messageid" : 2208,
            "viewed" : ISODate("2015-10-02T12:20:00Z"),
        },
        {
            "messageid" : 2263,
            "viewed" : ISODate("2015-01-15T07:50:00Z"),
        }
    ]
}
```

I want users who have viewed 3 or more distinct messages in a specified time period.

Example Query:

> Give me users those who have viewed 3 or more distinct messages between 2015-01-01 to 2015-11-30

Expected Result: `{userid: 2}`

Note: `(userid: 1)` has also viewed 3 messages in specified date range but they are not distinct messages.

Please help me build the MongoDB select query.

Comment: I tried using following aggregation query but it took so much time as i have around 5 million records in my collection.


    db.userDetails.aggregate( { $match: { userid:{$in:[225144,3]} } }, {$unwind: "$open"}, { $match: { "open.viewed":{$gte:15010100, $lte:15063048} } }, { $group: {_id:"$userid", open: {$addToSet: "$open"}} }, {$out: "segment"})

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use aggregation, such as

```
db.userDetails.aggregate( [
    { $unwind: "$open" }, 
    { $match: { 
        "open.viewed": { $gte: ISODate( new Date("2015-01-01").toISOString()), $lte: ISODate( new Date("2015-11-30").toISOString()) 
        } 
    }}, 
    { $group: {
        _id: "$userid", 
        open_messageids: { $addToSet: "$open.messageid" }
    }}, 
    { $unwind: "$open_messageids" }, 
    { $group: { 
        _id: null, 
        count: { $sum: 1 } 
    }},
    { $match: { count : { $gte : 3 } } }
])
```

Comment: I have changed my dates to Integers.  
i.e. '2015-11-30 12:00:00' => 15113012  
  
I used following query now and it is still giving me empty result.  
  
db.userDetails.aggregate( [{$unwind: "$open"}, { $match: { "open.viewed":{$gte:15010100, $lte:15123048 } } }, { $group: {_id:"$userid", open_messageids: {$addToSet: "$open.messageid"}} }, { $unwind: "$open_messageids"}, { $group: { _id:"$userid", count: { $sum: 1 } } },{ $match: { count : { $gte : 3 } } }, {$out:"segment"} ])

Comment: please check 'viewed' date type

Comment: Sorry i missed something then, actual result that i got is  { "_id" : null, "count" : 118314 }  
I want records with userid.

Comment: last group by will be { _id: null... not _id:"$userId"

Comment: Hi @skmahwar,  it is working fine. Thanks for the help. I just changed "$userid" by "_id" in last $group.